# Google Static Map occasionally maps the path differently to the dynamic google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I extract coordinates on google maps by plotting an overlay (exhibit A).
I then reuse these same coordinates as the path variable in the google static map (exhibit B) and for some locations, it does not plot to the same location.

I then typed out a CSV file that I can import into the google maps web app to add a new overlay and it mapped correctly, which tells me there is something strange happening in the google maps static map.

Sample CSV import for testing overlay

```
lat,lon,title,
-26.052937841371918,28.060764598707202,Test 1,
-26.052994468511443,28.060752528766635,Test 2,
-26.05304868595982,28.06076996312523,Test 3,
-26.053040252136153,28.061060982803347,Test 4,
-26.052978805688355,28.060979845980647,Test 5,
-26.052934226872722,28.06093357787514,Test 6,
```

Exhibit A:

[image]

Exhibit B:
[image]

Exhibit B in terms of the google static map:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&zoom=20&size=500x500&maptype=satellite&geodesic=true&path=color%3A0x00000000%7Cweight%3A1%7Cfillcolor%3Aorange%7C-26.052950%2C28.060751%7C-26.052940%2C28.060928%7C-26.053038%2C28.061048%7C-26.053054%2C28.060762&key=[input your google API key here]
```

The exact same code generates the following output also (correct output)

Sample 1:

[image]

Sample 2:

[image]

So it isn't an issue of the code, as most outputs are correct, but rather something strange occurs on specific instances that as you can see in Exhibit B, there is a non-negligible shift in the points of latitude.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question how you plot the points in the first place and what exact steps you take afterwards. You should provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the whole issue. That said, if you are sure your code isn't the problem, I'd suggest you browse the [Maps Static API issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188843) for similar existing issues or file a new bug if you can't find an existing one.

Comment: @MrUpsidown
I have the example of how the points are used in the static maps URL, and I provided the CSV of the points. Let me know if more is needed?

Comment: *I extract coordinates on google maps by plotting an overlay* - we don't know how you do that. Have you found a pattern? Why does it work in one case, not the other one? Does it work in a specific region of the world, not another one? Have you tried plotting your points with the standard ROADMAP map type instead of the SATELLITE mode? Does it make a difference?